# Why I get an error as "redeclaration of const phone_price" in console?

Tags: javascript, console

**Question1:** Why do I get this error on my browser(firefox):

`redeclaration of const phone_price`

[image]

**But here, An error is not thrown:**

```js
const phone_price = 102.22;
const tax = 0.08;
const price_thereshold = 230;
const accessory = 10;

var account_bank = 310;
var amount = 0;

function withTax(amt){
  return amt * tax;
}
function formatted_price(amt){
  return "$" + amt.toFixed(2);
}

while(amount < account_bank){
  amount = amount + phone_price;
  if(amount < price_thereshold){
    amount = amount + accessory;
  }
}

amount = amount + withTax(amount);
amount = formatted_price(amount);

console.log("your purchase price: " + amount);

if(amount > account_bank){
  console.log("you haven't afford for your purchase");
}
```

**Question 2:** Why does the second console not run?

Comment: "*Why do I get this error on my browser(firefox)*" - because likely you previously already did declare that variable, e.g. when attempting to run the same code snippet twice in the console

Comment: "*Why does the second console not run?*" - because `"$352.79" > 310` is false. Don't compare strings to intergers. Omit the `amount = formatted_price(amount);` statement, call `formatted_price` only for the output.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot. I got the answer to both. I will accept it if you show it as an answer:)